# How to get checkbox value in Datagrid in WPF in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have a datagrid in wpf application in c#.

see this image:

[image]

I want to check all rows that their checkbox column is checked.
how can i do that?

Comment: You want all rows which have their checkboxes checked ?

Comment: no, i want to get value of rows that their checkboxes is checked, maybe 1 row maybe 10 rows or all rows

Comment: What do you mean by value of rows ?

Comment: this datagrid shows a company customers, first column is customer name, i want to get value customer name if checkbox is checked on this row

Comment: any idea?  @AnjumSKhan

Comment: You have to use `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` with `SelectedValuePath`. `SelectedItem="{Binding ChosenCustomer, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` , `ChosenCustomer` is normal property of type `Customer`.